# what is the difference between SUBSTRING and SUBSTR functions (SQL)?

Tags: sql, oracle

before I used :

```
entityManagerFactory.createQuery("select p FROM Pays p where SUBSTRING(p.libeleClient, 0,1)
```

but when I use this query :

```
entityManagerFactory.createQuery("select p FROM Pays p where SUBSTR(p.libeleClient, 0,1)
```

I get an exception :(

who to remplace SUBSTRING by SUBSTR ?

Comment: `SUBSTRING` is not supported by Oracle.

Comment: the SUBSTRING function is not supported !

Answer (score 4):

SUBSTR is the function from Oracle

SUBSTRING is the function from MySql

depends on DB which u r using

EDIT:

try to edit your java code like below

```
String query = "select p FROM Pays p where SUBSTRING(p.libeleClient, 0,1)";


        // from Connection Object (connection)
        DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
        //If the DB is Oracle 
          if(meta.getDatabaseProductName()).contains("Oracle")) {
              entityManagerFactory.createQuery(query.replace("SUBSTRING", "SUBSTR"));
          }// If the DB not Oracle , any Other like MySql 
          else {
              entityManagerFactory.createQuery(query);
          }
```

Comment: BUT WHO TO USE THE SUBSTR FUNCTION?

Comment: In java u have to write a pice of code in java to identify Your database and accroding to that you need to edit your sql query.

Comment: thank you for answer. Here are more details on my problem :       WsWebService ws;                                            ws.sendQuery("Select Label From Pays Where SUBSTRING(Label,0,1)='A'",
Pays.class);

Comment: Now I am not using entityManagerFactory.createQuery() but the ws.sendQuery()

Comment: WsWebService is web service or just a java object

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18044/discussion-between-pradeep-and-berber5)

Answer (score 2):

substring is the sql operation defined in the sql standard ISE:IEC 9075:1992.

substr is an old syntax used by oracle. This wrong syntax is completely inconsistent with sql usage of real english words, never abbreviations.

Oracle still does not support the standard syntax.

Did anyone wrote a hack in oracle to support the standard syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what exception you get, but I 'm guessing it's a syntax error.   The correct syntax for Oracle's SUBSTR() is ...

```
where SUBSTR(p.libeleClient, 0,1) = 'X'
```

...(or whatever).  That is the first occurence of a single character must equal; some specified value.  SUBSTR() is not a boolean function.

Whereas SUBSTRING() is not an oracle function at all.  Either you've borrowed the syntax from some other database, or you're using a bespoke function without realising it.

---

> "I tried your suggestion but it does not work"

Do you get an error?  Or do you mean it doesn't return any records?  Because I have given a perfectly valid usage, [as defined in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions169.htm#i87066).  But you haven't given any examples of your data, so it's almost impossible for me to provide a solution which will return rows from your database.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it does not work. but when I used this SUBSTR(Label,-2)='A' I get All DATA :(